# How to print particular data in visualforce page?

Tags: commandbutton

I have visualforce page that contains report card. This page have command button like **Back to page**  and **Print** . I am using for Print command button

apex:commandLink value="Print" onclick="window.print();"

This is printing along with buttons. but i don't want to print command buttons after we done print.
Can anyone please help to how to print page with only required data.

Comment: when you click print set some value and don't display the button.

Comment: i am using this <apex:commandLink value="Print" onclick="window.print();"/>. In this how can we hide buttons

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample page

```html
     <apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandlink styleClass="cButtons" value="Print" reRender="dummy" onclick="printMyPartialPage();"/>
        adfas<br/>
        asdfs<br/>
        asdfasdfasdfasdf<br/>
        
        asdfasdfasdfasdfasd <br/>
        
    </apex:form>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"/>
    
    <Script>
        function printMyPartialPage(){
            $('.cButtons').hide();
            window.print();    
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: it is firing error "Unsupported attribute class in &lt;apex:commandLink&gt; in class"

Comment: Use styleClass instead of class. Updated my answer

Comment: ok now error is not firing, but when i click on Print link it not responding...  it is redirecting to same page..

Comment: Did you check for console errors? Have you included jQuery in your page? I hope you know what I am talking about.

Comment: I din't get you, But i checked in developer console errors... no errors in the logs. I'm Sorry for making you confuse..

Comment: I have updated a functional page for you :)

Comment: The page you updated is still showing the button Back to Page after i print. I tried with apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="false", But the page should be with showheader="True" sidebar="True". After i click on the print then only it should be like all false. I hope you understand And i appreciate for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for you - https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2008/06/dynamically-cho.html.

You can dynamically render your page as PDF and use the 'chooserender' variable in the above link to hide your command buttons

Comment: This link is somewhat helping, but the print is not coming properly. some data missing. Thanks Ansuman

Answer (score 0):

You would have to place the content to print in a separate section say div. And use command button in a different section and use below code:

```
<div id="printDiv">
<apex:pageblock>
...
...Your Page content to print....
...
</apex:pageBlock>
</div>
<apex:commandLink onclick="myFunction('printDiv')" value="Print"/>
```

The JS function:

> `function myFunction(printDiv) {
>       var printContent = document.getElementById(printDiv).innerHTML;
>       var w = window.open();
>       w.document.write(printContent);
>       w.print();
>       w.close();
>   }`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]
Use the below code to provide a print option of your entire VFpage

> 

```
    <tr>    
        <td align="right"><a href="javascript:window.print();">Print</a></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: this does not answer the question, the OP is specifically asking to print only specific data, not the whole page.